# Wrap C-API with types as enums in C++

Tags: c++, c, templates

Currently, I write a C++ Wrapper for a C-Library which acts as the driver for a camera. The camera can be set with properties that can be `float`, `bool` or `int`. Each property has an ID which is member of an `enum PropId`. For each of these types, there is an attribute information `struct`, a function to get and set the value:

```
GetPropertyAttribsI
GetPropertyAttribsB
GetPropertyAttribsF
PropAttribsI
PropAttribsF
PropAttribsB
SetPropertyValueI
SetPropertyValueF
SetPropertyValueB
```

My problem is now that I want to write code to:

1. **Check whether the property value to set is in bounds**, else sets it to default. The bounds and default can be looked up in the `PropAttribs struct`, which can be initialized with the respective `GetPropertyAttribs` function.
2. **Set the property** with the corresponding `SetPropertyValue(I,B,F)`

I can look up the type of the property, it is in an `enum (PROP_TYPE_INT, PROP_TYPE_FLOAT, PROP_TYPE_BOOL)`.

So what I want is a **function**:

```
checkAndSanitizeProperty(T& value, PropId property)
```

that checks whether a given property is in bounds, else sets it to default.

The skeleton would be the following, but I do not know how I can make it so generic with template parameters that it is usable for `bool` and `float` without copying. The function for setting parameters is very similar to that, and should have the same solution if any is found.

```
void CameraHandle::checkAndSanitizeProperty(int& value, VRmPropId property, std::string name) {
  VRmPropInfo propInfo;
  VRM_CHECK(VRmUsbCamGetPropertyInfo(device, property, &propInfo));

  if (VRM_PROP_TYPE_INT != propInfo.m_type) {
    ROS_ERROR("Invalid type of property!");
  }

  VRmPropAttribsI attribs;
  VRmUsbCamGetPropertyAttribsI(device, property, &attribs);
  if (value < attribs.m_min || value > attribs.m_max) {
    ROS_WARN("Invalid value for parameter %s, has to be in [%d,%d], but was: %d",
             name.c_str(),
             attribs.m_min,
             attribs.m_max,
             value);

    ROS_WARN("Default will be used for %s: %d", name.c_str(), attribs.m_default);
    value = attribs.m_default;
  }
}
```

What gets on my nerves is that I have to repeat a lot of code, so I search for a cleaner solution. I do not mainly use C++, so I haven't got too much experience with template magic or C++ idioms.

Answer (score 2):

Macro hackery.

```
#define CONCAT2( A, B ) A##B
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT2(A,B)

#define MAP_STRUCT( X ) \
  template<class T> struct X; \
  template<class T> using CONCAT(X,_t) = typename X<T>::type; \
  template<> struct X<int> { \
    using type= CONCAT(X, I); \
  }; \
  template<> struct X<float> { \
    using type= CONCAT(X, F); \
  }; \
  template<> struct X<bool> { \
    using type= CONCAT(X, B); \
  };
```

takes a base structure name like `VRmPropAttribs` and makes it so that `VRmPropAttribs_t<int>` is `VRmPropAttribsI`.

```
#define CALL(X) CONCAT( call_, X )
#define MAP_FUNC_CALL(X) \
  template<class T> \
  struct CALL( X ); \
  template<> struct CALL(X)<int> { \
    template<class...Args> \
    auto operator()(Args&&...args)const \
    -> decltype( CONCAT(X,I)(std::declval<Args>()...) ) { \
      return CONCAT(X,I)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
    } \
  }; \
```

etc for B and F.

```
 #define MAP_FUNC(X) \
    MAP_FUNC_CALL(X) \
    template<class T, class...Args> \
    auto X(Args&&...args) \
    -> typename std::result_of< CALL(X)(Args...) > \
    { return CALL(X)<T>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
```

which defines a function template named `X` that, when passed `int`, calls `XI` with the same arguments.

Now, this doesn't handle your `%d` format strings and the like, but you can do things like:

VRmPropAttribs attribs;
   VRmUsbCamGetPropertyAttribs(device, property, &attribs);
after you use the above macros.  And once you can do the above, you can replace `int` with `T` and make your method a template method.

You'll also want a better version of `VRM_PROP_TYPE_INT`:

```
template<class T> struct vrm_prop_type{};
template<> struct vrm_prop_type<int>:
  std::integral_constant<int, VRM_PROP_TYPE_INT>
{};
```

etc lets you do:

```
vrm_prop_type<T>{} != propInfo.m_type
```

checks.

Comment: That looks really cool. Sadly, I assume that it is also less readable and maintainable than simply copying the function for each type.

Comment: @reindeer if you have only 1 or 2 functions, writing what the macros produce manually is better than using said macros.  And you end up with a uniform business-logic function, which can be nice.